# Can I list queues in Azure Service Bus for accounts restricted to portions of the namespace?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have several accounts (service identities) on our main Azure Service Bus account which are restricted to portions of the namespace so they can't interfere with each other.  For example,  account foo1 has Send, Listen, Manage rights to /foo1, and foo2 has Send, Listen, Manage rights to /foo2.  That way foo1 can't read/write/delete any queues defined by foo2.

Is there a way for foo1 to get a listing of all queues it has access to?  Calling the list queues API seems to get all queues rooted at /, which foo1 doesn't have access to and so the call fails with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because **Service Bus** and **ACS** are separate components - you will have to do the ACS lookup yourself to determine what SB namespaces an ACS account has access to. Take a look at the [ACS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh278947) for querying [Rule Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180763) and [SBAzTool's `Microsoft.ServiceBus.AccessControlExtensions`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Authorization-SBAzTool-6fd76d93/view/SourceCode) for [quick integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868045.aspx#sec23).